# Not able to access REST within EAR

Tags: rest, war

I am using JBoss to deploy my EAR application which contains a RESTful War file.
I am using javax.was.rs.ApplicationPath, and the REST is accessible and running ok when I deploy the WAR directly on the server.

Problem is when I deploy it within the EAR file, I am not able to access it.

In the application.xml, I have the following

```
<module>
  <web>
    <web-uri>TP-Server.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>/api</context-root>
  </web>
</module>
```

In the javax.ws.rs.Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
    public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

Is there any special configuration to make REST works in EAR?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got problem solved. i think i just tried to republished the app.